# SSLCertVerificationError in jupiter notebook

Tags: python-3.9, junit-jupiter

```
from urllib.request import urlopen  
html = urlopen('http://pythonscraping.com/pages/page1.html')  
print(html.read())
```

this code i have run but still im getting error i have tried to install openssl packages and upgrade certifi

Answer (score 0):

The reason you got error is the cert of that website expired. Below is a suggested solution:

```
import urllib
import ssl

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

html=urlopen("https://pythonscraping.com/pages/page1.html", context=ctx)
print(html.read())
```